# Opencart Images Issue after SSL append

Tags: image, ssl, opencart

I have this website (it is in Romanian) [www.daiclick.ro](http://www.daiclick.ro) running Opencart 3.0.3.6.
After adding SSL, some of the images have been messed up but only when using Firefox. In Google Chrome everything works fine.
I have edited the seetings in config.php in both folders (root and admin), as follows:

config.php in root folder:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://daiclick.ro/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'https://daiclick.ro/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://daiclick.ro/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://daiclick.ro/image/');
```

and config.php in admin folder

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://daiclick.ro/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://daiclick.ro/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'https://daiclick.ro/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://daiclick.ro/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://daiclick.ro/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://daiclick.ro/image/');
```

As well I found a post that says to edit:

/catalog/model/tool/image.php
line 39

```
return HTTPS_IMAGE . 'image/' . $new_image;

return HTTP_IMAGE . 'image/' . $new_image;
```

and catalog/controller/common/header.php

about line 55

```
$this->data['icon'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_icon');

$this->data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

However, at the first section of code, mine looks like this:

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
        //return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $image_new;
        return HTTPS_IMAGE . $image_new;
    } else {
        //return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $image_new;
        return HTTP_IMAGE . $image_new;
    }
```

I tried uncommenting the first line $this->config->get('config_ssl') and it did noting. Note that I have $image_new instead of $new_image

As well, I enabled SSL from the Opencart Admin Panel.

Any thoughts? What else could be done? I mention I did not do the two suggestions that I found in the post.

Comment: "some of the images have been messed up" This does not mean anything. Show HTTP exchanges and what is wrong. But at this stage it might not be really programming related hence your question may be offtopic here.

Comment: Some images don't show. Instead, there are Xs that show. Images like icons. What do I need to do in order to show you HTTP exchanges?